# java jasypt suddenly crashes

Tags: java, jasypt

Since yesterday my textencrypter(jasypt) stopped working for no reason. Here is a code example and the error msg. Does anybody know what is going on?

Code example:

```
        StrongTextEncryptor crypter = new StrongTextEncryptor();
        crypter.setPassword("Password");
        crypter.encrypt("Test");
```

Error msg:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:773)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:566)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:644)
    at org.jasypt.util.text.StrongTextEncryptor.encrypt(StrongTextEncryptor.java:107)
    at A.main(A.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.NormalizerDataReader.<clinit>(NormalizerDataReader.java:300)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.NormalizerImpl.<init>(NormalizerImpl.java:288)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.NormalizerImpl.<clinit>(NormalizerImpl.java:35)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer$Mode.normalize(Normalizer.java:188)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer.normalize(Normalizer.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer.normalize(Normalizer.java:1146)
    at org.jasypt.normalization.Normalizer.normalizeWithIcu4j(Normalizer.java:205)
    at org.jasypt.normalization.Normalizer.normalizeToNfc(Normalizer.java:129)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:718)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
    at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:188)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What is your jvm version ?

Comment: 1.8.0_261 since the last update, jasypt is broken.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I saw this error today and I have no idea, why it stopped working...

Answer (score 18):

This is not a direct answer, but I'm putting it here in case someone runs upon the issue.

Using Java 1.8.0_275, I was getting a

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

when running the `encrypt.sh`.

Jasypt version 1.9.3 is using an old version of icu4j-3.4.4.jar. I replaced the icu4j-3.4.4.jar with [icu4j-68_2.jar](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-68-2) then I was able to run:

`./encrypt.sh input=password password=aSecret algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES`

without error.

For more information, see https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt/issues/58. Even though this is a little different from how you're running jasypt, I'd recommend updating the icu4j.jar and try again.

Comment: that worked also with windows version encrypt.bat

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be related (at least in my case) to icu4j.
Found this commit on jasypt Github https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt/commit/d384f9a755af2938bc142f7575365bee42ba5f22
Updated dependency and application started running.

Comment: I didn't see a release with that commit in it. Just build it locally?

Comment: In practise I just replaced the old icu4j jar file in my apps lib directory with this one https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/67.1/icu4j-67.1.jar

Comment: Did the following with maven pom:
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>          
      <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>             
                    <version>1.9.2</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
     <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
   <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
   <version>67.1</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

A jasypt issue 44 comment on github says just to remove the old icu4j-3.4.4.jar.  IOW, don't bother tracking down a replacement.  Worked OK for me.  :-)  Thanks `Brad Rippe` for providing the clue!

`DSOANS commented on Aug 24, 2020`

> It appears the fix is to REMOVE the com.ibm.icu4j jar
> (icu4j-3.4.4.jar) file from the distribution - at least that seems to
> have worked for us.

https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt/issues/44